# Find a best fuzzy match for a string

Tags: python, performance, strings, search, edit-distance

I am trying to find a best match for a name within a list of names.

I came up with the below code, which works, but I feel that the creation of the intermediate `ratios` list is not the best solution performance-wise.

Could it be somehow replaced? Would `reduce` be a good fit here (I have tried it, but could not get the index of best match and its value at the same time).

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

name_to_match = 'john'
names = ['mike', 'james', 'jon', 'jhn', 'jimmy', 'john']
ratios = [fuzz.ratio(name_to_match, name) for name in names]
best_match = names[ratios.index(max(ratios))]
print(best_match) # output is 'john'
```

Comment: Someone else asked about this on stack overflow once before, and I suggested they try downloading [python-levenshtein](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/) since the github page suggests it may speed up execution by 4-10x. They later confirmed that it did in fact speed up their solution, so you may want to try that as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take advantage of [the `key` argument to `max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> The *key* argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort).

```
best_match = max(names, key=lambda name: fuzz.ratio(name_to_match, name))
```

Answer (score 2):

fuzzywuzzy [already includes functionality](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy#Process) to return only the best match. unless you need it sorted like 200_success's solution, this would be the easiest:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
choices = ["Atlanta Falcons", "New York Jets", "New York Giants", "Dallas Cowboys"]
process.extractOne("cowboys", choices)
# returns ("Dallas Cowboys", 90)
```