# Substring match within a text for given keywords

Tags: python

**Goal:**

Look for a substring match within a text for given Keywords. Keep the substring match if the levenshtein distance is smaller than the length of the Keyword divided by (x=10), else return an empty list.

(First of all my apologies if the code is of lower quality. I am quite good in R but very new to Python.)

**Current implementation:**

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches
import math

def fuzzy_extract(qs, ls, threshold, max_dist):
    ret = []
    for word, _ in process.extractBests(qs, (ls,), score_cutoff = threshold):
        for match in find_near_matches(qs, word, max_l_dist = max_dist):
            word = word[match.start:match.end]
            ret.append({"kw": qs, "word": word, "dist": match.dist})
    return(ret)

def get_match(text, keywords, treshold):
    keywords = [keyword.lower() for keyword in keywords]
    text = text.lower()
    
    candidates = []
    for li in [fuzzy_extract(query_string, text, 0, 1) for query_string in keywords]:
        if len(li) > 0:
            for di in li:
                if di["dist"] <= math.ceil(len(di["word"])/treshold):
                    candidates.append(di)
    
    if(len(candidates) == 0):
        return([])

    out = str(candidates[0]["kw"])
    return(out)

keywords = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
text = "nana is Looking for an aple."

print(get_match(text, keywords, 10))
```

For me the part in the middle looks neither efficient and also not very declarative.
With part in the middle i mean the Code following:

```
for li in [fuzzy_extract(query_string, text, 0, 1) for query_string in keywords]:
```

I started with something longer but more declarative:

```
candidates = [fuzzy_extract(query_string, ocr_text, 0, 1) for query_string in keywords_ordering]
lens = [len(candidate) > 0 for candidate in candidates]
candidate_lengths = list(compress(candidates, lens))
filtered = [candidate_length[0]["dist"] < math.ceil(len(candidate_length[0]["word"])/10) for candidate_length in candidate_lengths] 
candidate_filtered = list(compress(candidate_lengths, filtered))
```

In R i would make usage of pipes for These cases to avoid the undeclarative variables in between.

**Similar Topics:**

[Find a best fuzzy match for a string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215174/find-a-best-fuzzy-match-for-a-string)

(Difference is that in this question match candidates are compared to a single word and to a substring of a text).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36132391/3502164

Custom implementation, rather long.

Answer (score 5):

## Unnecessary parentheses

Switch the following:

```
return(...) -> return ...
if(...) -> if ...
```

You switch between the two, probably due to coming from another language. Just try to be consistent and don't use parentheses if you don't have to.

## Type Hints

You can use type hints to display what types of parameters are accepted, and what types of values are returned, if any.

```
def fuzzy_extract(query_string: str, match_string: str, threshold: int, max_dist: int):
def get_match(text: str, keywords: List[str], threshold: int):
```

*The `List` is imported by `from typing import List`*

## Simplify your loops

Instead of checking `if len(li) > = 0`, you can do that check inside the list comprehension. Also, I would move that outside of the loop into its own variable.

```
extracted = [fuzzy_extract(query_string, text, 0, 1) for query_string in keywords if len(query_string) > 0]
```

## Empty lists

Instead of checking if the length of the list is 0, simply check if the list is `None`. An empty list is implicitly `None`.

```
if not candidates:
```

## Default Parameters

When passing default parameters, there shouldn't be a space before or after the `=`.

```
for word, _ in process.extractBests(query_string, (match_string,), score_cutoff=threshold):
        for match in find_near_matches(query_string, word, max_l_dist=max_dist):
```

## Final Code

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches
import math

from typing import List

def fuzzy_extract(query_string: str, match_string: str, threshold: int, max_dist: int):
    matches = []
    for word, _ in process.extractBests(query_string, (match_string,), score_cutoff=threshold):
        for match in find_near_matches(query_string, word, max_l_dist=max_dist):
            word = word[match.start:match.end]
            matches.append({"kw": query_string, "word": word, "dist": match.dist})
    return matches

def get_match(text: str, keywords: List[str], threshold: int):
    keywords = [keyword.lower() for keyword in keywords]
    text = text.lower()

    canidates = []
    extracted = [fuzzy_extract(query_string, text, 0, 1) for query_string in keywords if len(query_string) > 0]
    for item in extracted:
        for di in item:
            if di["dist"] <= math.ceil(len(di["word"]) / threshold):
                canidates.append(di)

    if not canidates:
        return []

    result = str(canidates[0]["kw"])
    return result

keywords = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
text = "nana is Looking for an aple."

print(get_match(text, keywords, 10))
```

Comment: I would make `extracted` a generator instead of a list.  Also, it seems odd to return `[]` for no match.  I'd return `None` or an empty str.